# How can select line break string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some table in my project and these table has some line break string. I want to select data of these table by using these line break string . but i can't do that. Please help me how can i select data by using line break string

Comment: `if(strstr($string, "\n")) {` ?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name REGEXP "\n";
```

Comment: I want to search a specific data by using these line break string.

Comment: can you give sample example?

Comment: suppose i insert data 1. back pain , then take new line and 2 chest pain in the mysql database . then i want to find this type of data if exist or not and count this type of data. i use like statement in mysql but when is search this data by using a part of this string or whole string that can't find any thing